# zsh: menu completion for glob

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

In `zsh`, if I type `vim *.txt` then <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it expands to `vim f1.txt f2.txt f3.txt`.

How can I make it show a completion menu listing files matching the pattern, so I can select a single file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
% PS1='%% ' exec zsh -f
% autoload -U compinit && compinit
% setopt GLOB_COMPLETE
% touch aa ab ac ad
% vim a*
```

Will cycle through the options; and then for a menu (on, like, everything)

```
% zstyle ':completion*:default' menu 'select=0'
% vim a*
```

For more information see `zshoptions(1)` and the "[From Bash to Z Shell](http://www.bash2zsh.com)" book for slightly readable docs on the completion system.

Menu completion on demand would require a custom widget:

```
function blaah {
  local revert
  revert=0
  if [[ $options[(k)globcomplete] = off ]]; then
    setopt globcomplete
    revert=1
  fi
  zle menu-expand-or-complete
  if [[ $revert -eq 1 ]]; then
    unsetopt globcomplete
  fi
}
zle -N blaah

# or perhaps additionally 'vicmd' or instead 'emacs', depending
binkey -M viins "^W" blaah
```

Comment: Thanks! `setopt GLOB_COMPLETE` works; but it is globally. Is there a `bindkey` to do "menu complete" (or "expand") on demand?

Comment: @aggu you'll need a widget, I believe

Comment: how do I "see `zshoptions(1)`"?

Comment: @cambunctious `manpage(section)` translates to the `man section manpage` command so `man 1 zshoptions`